# Composer can't access local Satis server

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package.json, satis

I am hosting a Satis Private Repository currently on my local machine while I do some debugging and testing. I have added a repository too which currently just contains a project on GitLab which included a composer package.

Currently it is being pulled from a docker image, and is hosted at localhost:8002.

My repository is setup in my Laravel project as follows:

```
"repositories": [
    { "packagist": false },
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://localhost:8002/packages.json"
    }],
```

And if I navigate to that URL in my browser I get the following output:

```
{
    "packages": [],
    "includes": {
        "include/all$949e06d91b8be4b54109a0b06c31805a5735a1ba.json": {
            "sha1": "949e06d91b8be4b54109a0b06c31805a5735a1ba"
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try to composer update the Laravel project, I get the following errors depending on if I execute it from within the container.

```
 The "http://localhost:8002/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout) 

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://localhost:8002/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Address not available
```

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction at all I would really appreciate it, as I am scratching my head here.

Comment: Where are you running composer? The host machine where you run the satis container? Or a different container?

Comment: I am trying two different methods. First one using composer installed on my local machine, second one spinning up a new docker container using docker run --rm -v /$(PWD):/app composer update
Both produce similar outputs

Comment: The second would logically fail, since "localhost" it's the container, not your host system.

Comment: So then the first one is the one that produces the HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout error